# Finding the closest values in an array

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting

Hoping someone can help, I'm working on a build for a competition at the moment - the object is for users to guess the time it takes an escapologist to perform an act, so you'd have the following scenario:

Act 1 - Escapologist finishes in 2mins 30 seconds

Say you have 5 guesses:

Name 1: 1min 20

Name 2: 2min 20

Name 3: 5min 50

Name 4: 6min 10

Name 5: 3min 40

When the escapologist has finished, they'd like to be able to show the top 4 results, so in this case it'll be:

Name 2: 2min 20

Name 1: 1min 20

Name 5: 3min 40

Name 3: 4min 50

I'm using WordPress at the moment, so my query is

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'entry', 
'posts_per_page' => 4, 
'order'     => 'ASC',
'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
'meta_key'  => 'in_seconds', 

'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'key'     => 'act',
        'value'   => $post->ID,
        'compare' => '=',
    ),
    array(
        'key'     => 'in_seconds',
        'value'   => $seconds,
        'type'    => 'numeric',
        'compare' => '>=',
    ),
),
);
```

This gets me the closest values, but only if they're higher, not lower. 
Obviously I'd prefer if there was a way to do this using wp_query, but if anyone knew a way to do it (even it was a heavy multiple loop) - I'd be eternally grateful!

For reference, all the guesses are stored in the database in seconds.

Hoping you can help!
Thanks, 
Andy :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it's not possible to achieve what you want just using a simple WP_Query. Although you should be able to order the posts by the absolute value  of the difference between posts *seconds* and the desired *seconds*. Your code will be something like:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 4, 
    'order'     => 'ASC',
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key'  => 'in_seconds', 
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'     => 'act',
            'value'   => $post->ID,
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
    ),
);
```

The posts_orderby filter to change the order behaviour:

```
global $seconds_where;
$seconds_where = $seconds;
function seconds_posts_orderby( $orderby ) {
    $orderby = " ABS($seconds - meta_value) ASC";
    return $orderby;
}
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'seconds_posts_orderby');
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
remove_filter('posts_orderby', 'seconds_posts_orderby');
```

It's just a start, but I hope this helps.

Comment: You're welcome, @imandypugh! Can you accept the answer so? :D

Comment: It won't allow me for some reason Felipe, I think because I'm a new user? As soon as it allows me I'll accept it! Thank you!